# Under what conditions can we consider the coefficient of restitution to be independent of velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, education, material-science

In high-school mathematics textbooks a bouncing ball is often considered as an example of an exponential decay.

One can easily derive this if one assumes that the [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) is independent of velocity.

I know however that there are multiple phenomena which may result in velocity dependent energy loss in colission:

- plastic deformations
- generated waves modes in the surface and in the ball
- some viscoelastic effects

compare: [Behavior of one inelastic ball bouncing repeatedly off the ground](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs100510050283) also [here](http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~falcon/EPJB98a/EPJB98a.pdf).

So under what conditions one can consider the coefficient of restitution as a constant, independent of velocity and why? What are the basic physical reasons to consider it (under special circumstances) as a constant?

Since I have high-school examples in mind, it might perhaps easier to narrow down the question to certain typical examples ocurring in math or physics high school text books:

- a metal ball (diameter 2cm) released (from rest) from 1m height
- a wooden ball (diameter 2cm) released (from rest) from 1m height
- a tennis ball released (from rest) from 2m height
- a basketball released (from rest) from 3m height

Comment: High school texts are usually made more simple, so students grasp the fundamentals. As real physics would hamper that understanding we assume things like no friction, no quantum effects, unbreakable ropes and rods, etc. So we assume velocity independence, while actually it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the material of the bouncing object and the material on which it is bouncing.

There are no mathematical formulas to predict this unfortunately and it's entirely found by experiments:

I've found this study for example exploring the COR for different materials bouncing on different surfaces:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Khairul-Ismail-6/publication/260991737_Coefficient_of_restitution_of_sports_balls_A_normal_drop_test/links/57a021d808aec29aed214c06/Coefficient-of-restitution-of-sports-balls-A-normal-drop-test.pdf?origin=publication_detail

[image]

[image]